# Android parse through xml

Tags: android, xml

there's this XML that I have to obtain certain info from, format is:

```
<Tag1
    name="something"
    target="something">
    <param name="url">Some url</param>
    <param name="tag">Some tag</param>
</Tag1>
```

the thing is I have to first check if "Some url" contained in param name="url" exists (as some xml entries might not include it) and, if it does, get Tag1 name, any suggestions?

Edit:

Was not at office when I posted question, here's the code I'm currently using (also, was able to get the URL inside param name="url")

```
InputStream inputStream = getActivity().getAssets().open("some_xml.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(inputStream);
Element element = document.getDocumentElement();
element.normalize();
NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("Tag1");
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element element2 = (Element) node;
        if (element2.getElementsByTagName("param") != null){
            NodeList innerNodes = element2.getElementsByTagName("param");
            for (int j = 0; j < innerNodes.getLength(); j++){
                Element element3 = (Element) innerNodes.item(j);
                Log.d("XMLNode", element3.getNodeName());
                Node child = element3.getFirstChild();
                if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
                    CharacterData characterData = (CharacterData) child;
                    Log.d("XMLURL", characterData.getData());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now the problem is that when the xml entry has param name="url" and param name="tag" I'll get both the URL and Tag returned and need to only catch the URL (as sometimes param name="tag" is above param name="url"), i tried using

```
if (element3.getAttribute("Url") != null
```

to specify that it should catch the url only but apparently it does nothing as it goes through on the param name="tag" comparison. Any suggestions on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What had you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is pretty vague and doesn't show what code you've tried so far. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link on how to ask a good question for more help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this GSON XML parser library for converting your xml response.

https://github.com/stanfy/gson-xml

I use Retrofit for API hit and for auto parse to model.

Checkout here : https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-how-to-integrate-xml-converter